# HorizontalScrollView how to save scroll position on refresh

Tags: android

I have the following layout which is a row of a vertical RecyclerView that contains a HorizontalScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

         <me.test.myCustomView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </HorizontalScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I try to scroll horizontally in a row and than call notifyItemChanged(int position) to refresh the current row which i just scrolled ,the layout completely refresh and the scroll position of the HorizontalScrollView returns to 0.

How can i save the x scroll position when i refresh one of the rows of the recycleView so that once onBindViewHolder is called again i can retrieve the scroll position and set it to the HorizontalScrollView ?

Edit :add code for adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter .ViewHolder>  {

    List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<StepData> data) {
     this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;

      v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.testing, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {



holder.customView.setData(this.data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));


          holder.customView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    addItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
           });
               }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }


    public void addItem(int position) {

                     this.data.add(data.get(position).getExtraData())
                     notifyItemChanged(position);
                    notifyItemInserted(position+1);
     }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MyCustomViewcustomView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
             customView = (MyCustomView) v.findViewById(R.id.myCustomView);

        }



    }



}
```

Comment: Post the code of the adapter

Comment: ok i added the code

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite understanding why you call `notifyItemChanged` to refresh the current row after scrolling to an item.

However, according to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), there are two methods you can use to save and restore state of the `HorizontalScrollView`:

> onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) Hook allowing a view to
>   re-apply a representation of its internal state that had previously
>   been generated by onSaveInstanceState().
>
> onSaveInstanceState() Hook allowing a view to generate a
>   representation of its internal state that can later be used to create
>   a new instance with that same state.

Comment: when i click in a row i add another row below it ,i need to refresh the row i  clicked to change something like the color of the text i drawn in my custom View  ,

Comment: but onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstance are used if activity is destroyed or during orientation i think  ,i don't think i need them in this case